# Centos Bootup Sends Serial message

Tags: linux, operating-system, usb, serial-port, centos

I have a setup where 2 pc with Linux is trying to communicate with RS232 Serial and Ethernet.
One of the PC, PC(B), I'm using USB<->RS232 connnector. When PC(A) issue a command for it to restart, PC(B) restarts but while booting up again, it received garbage messages at PC(A) from PC(B). PC(A) is still listening at the serial port. Some of these garbage messages happen to be what I'm listening for, which is not nice!

Anyone knows what those messages are? Is there a way to remove them? Does Centos sends some initializing message for testing purpose or what? How about other distribution of Linux?

Thanks in advance if anyone knows what is going on. =)

Comment: are you sure the USB<->RS232 is working fine? tried it against for example a modem?

Comment: @Hong Zhou I have come to the same place and wanted to ask the same question... was there any resolution to this? In fact, the bios sends a serial message, and centos sends another on bootup

Comment: As @TJD suggested, I think that is one way to handle this special case. When restart, PC A will look for those special message and drop them,and then follow usual sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect a USB serial converter to be well behaved through a system restart.  There's a period where the device is uninitialized, where it may produce glitches on the data lines.  Any toggles on the data line will appear as garbage Rx data on A.

If you want to do what you intend, you will have to put some code on A to look for the known startup message and discard any prepended garbage bytes.

Comment: Have you encounter before this same issue? 
So far, those messages seems to be the same. But I would not want to assume. Do you know if they are always fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed the garbage too. After trying several baud rates, I checked the signal using an oscilloscope*. It turned out that the message is a valid output, not the result of random signals. It is sent on 9600 baud, 8N1, and it is something like a binary countdown. Specifically the following bytes are sent (in hex):
11, 10, 0F, 0E, 0D, 0C, 0B, 0A, 09, 08, 07, 06, 05, 04, 03, 02, 01, 00

These bytes are sent around the same time as when the login prompt is displayed on the (video) console. There is another very short signal sequence quite earlier in the boot process, a fast, 20 us impulse followed by a 10 us one. This sequence is too short to decide whether it is actual data or only the byproduct of some kind of switching.

I have not noticed anything on a Windows 7 desktop with a PCI serial controller card, which uses the MCS9865 chip according to its documentation.

- The box is running Ubuntu 12.10. Linux kernel version is 3.5.0. The serial port controller is on a PCI Express card, lspci identifies it as "NetMos Technology PCIe 9922 Multi-I/O Controller".

Answer (score 0):

It could be the BIOS. A colleague of mine noticed that his laptop gave out the BIOS version number and some more info over RS-232 at 115200 bps during bootup.
Try listening at the RS-232 at different baud rates; you may see something that makes sense.